# How can I make my bot list servers it's in?

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm quite new to C# Discord bot-coding and after encountering a problem I thought to ask (I looked for an answer online, but no success)

I want to make the bot save data about the servers it's in.

Basically, my idea is:

- Every server has their own file that is named by the server's id `Storage\Guild\[guild id]`
- After someone changes bot's options in a server (for ex. prefix in server, who's staff in a server) the server's file is edited and saved.
- The server file contains: what prefix is chosen, who can access moderation commands and more.

I tried to do something like:
`Context.Client.Guilds.`, but got lost there.

Any help or tips on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I would suggest using some kind of Database, but it is also possible with text files ofc. At least save your stuff in JSON, it will make stuff way easier.

So what you can do is creating a new TextFile with the guildname on the `DiscordSocketClient#JoinedGuild` event, you can also set the default values such as the defualt prefix and stuff. Same for the other stuff you want to save.

So since the user needs to change the prefix via a command you can implement it there. Also when you work with text Files you need to make sure they exist before you access them and if they got deleted some how just create a new one. This also goes for all other stuff you want to save.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to using a database,  why not try sqlite?  Then I would use Entity Framework to connect your bot to your database.

Anyway,  Context.Client.Guilds is a IReadOnlyCollection so you have to treat it like a List or an Array.  Hope it helps!

```
foreach (var guild in Context.Client.Guilds)
{
      var guildName = guild.Name; 
      var owner = guild.Owner.Username;
      var totalUsers = guild.Users.Count();
}
```

Comment: Here is also a link to some source code you can use.   Its using sqlite and EF.   Here is the module where it looks at the list of Discord Guilds the bot is in:
https://gitlab.com/solarcloud7/DiscordBot/blob/master/Solarbot/Modules/NetworkInfo.cs

Comment: I've actually started to use databases, but, as one of my friends who owns a bot recommended, I use PostgreSQL. Databases seemed to be the way to count and save how many guilds the bot was in.